# Ruby on Rails: difference between .html_safe and sanitize()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sanitize, difference, html-safe

I have two pieces of code in my view:

```
<%= sanitize('<h3>winter</h3>') %>

<%= '<h3>winter</h3>'.html_safe %>
```

And they both seem to result in encoding html tags in a string provided. 
What is the difference between them and when should I use either?

Comment: Note that .sanitize was removed from rails in 5.1 (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28947)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Those are two very different methods.

`a = a.html_safe` will just mark string `a` as 'html_safe' and treat it as such afterwards [*(Marks a string as trusted safe. It will be inserted into HTML with no
additional escaping performed. It is your responsibility to ensure that the
string contains no malicious content. This method is equivalent to the
`raw` helper in views. It is recommended that you use `sanitize` instead of
this method. It should never be called on user input.)*](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/72ffeb9fe58c46bd556a85bed5214d8f482737a5/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb#L213).

`a.sanitize`, on the other hand, will html encode all tags and strip all attributes that are not specifically allowed (you can add/remove allowed tags and attributes if you want). Notice that user input is sanitized by default unless you specifically allowed html-markup with `raw` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw), which, by the way, uses `html_safe` to mark it as such.

Comment: So is `sanitize('<h3>winter</h3>').html_safe` redundant?

Comment: @lucas Yes indeed